# Populate SQL Database column with repeating sequential values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database `TestDB`. In this I have a table, say, `records`. I want to create a column `ID` that sequentially takes the value from 1 through 3 repeatedly.

For instance:

```
**Record#**      **ID**
Record1            1
Record2            2
Record3            3
Record4            1
Record5            2
Record6            3
Record7            1
Record8            2
Record9            3
Record10           1
Record11           2
Record12           3
```

And so on...

Is there an SQL query that can achieve this? Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: @Joe: It can be in any order. Just that each record should have one of these three values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select Record,(select COUNT(0) 
                from Table1 t1 
                where t1.Record <= t2.Record 
     )%3+1 as 'ID'
from Table1 t2 
ORDER BY Record;
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2c79/1)

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions could be to make the column as identity and reset the identity as it reaches its threshold value:

```
if exists(select id from records where id = 3)
begin
DBCC CHECKIDENT('records', RESEED, 0)
insert into records values('Record4')
end
else
begin
insert into records values('Record3')
end
```